# Kotlin Native use AXUIElement

Tags: swift, macos, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I try to get all the application's windows.

```kotlin
fun main() = memScoped {
    NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace.runningApplications()
        .map { it as NSRunningApplication }
        .filter { it.active }
        .forEach {
            val applicationRef = AXUIElementCreateApplication(it.processIdentifier)
            ...
        }
}
```

But i cant find the `AXUIElement` in kotlin native library but `AXUIElementRef` and `AXUIElementRefVar`. Many artical show the swift code to get `AXUIElement`, and i dont know how to change the code to kotlin.

The swift code like this:

```swift
if let pid = proToolsApp?.processIdentifier {
    var result = [AXUIElement]()
    var windowList: AnyObject? = nil // [AXUIElement]

    let appRef = AXUIElementCreateApplication(pid)
    if AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(appRef, "AXWindows" as CFString, &windowList) == .success {
            result = windowList as! [AXUIElement]
    }

    var docRef: AnyObject? = nil
    if AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(result.first!, "AXDocument" as CFString, &docRef) == .success {
        let result = docRef as! AXUIElement
        print("Found Document: \(result)")
        let filePath = result as! String
        print(filePath)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AXUIElement` is just a swift interpreted version of `AXUIElementRef` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/axuielementref?language=objc)

This should look something like this in kotlin:

```
fun windowTest() = memScoped {
    NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace.runningApplications()
        .map { it as NSRunningApplication }
        .filter { it.active }
        .forEach {
            val applicationRef = AXUIElementCreateApplication(it.processIdentifier)!!
            val output = alloc<CFTypeRefVar>()
            var result = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(
                applicationRef,
                attribute = kAXWindowsAttribute.toCFString(),
                value = output.ptr,
            )
            if (result != kAXErrorSuccess) {
                println("error $result")
                return@forEach
            }
            val firstOutput = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(output.value as CFArrayRef, 0)!!
            result = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(
                element = firstOutput.reinterpret(),
                attribute = kAXDocumentAttribute.toCFString(),
                value = output.ptr,
            )
            println("$result ${output.value}")
        }
}


fun String.toCFString(): CFStringRef = CFBridgingRetain(this)!!.reinterpret()
```

The second `AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue` returns `-25212 = kAXErrorNoValue` in my case, I'm not sure what's the problem, but I'm getting the same result in both swift/kotlin code